# No se devuelve el value de un input number cuando tiene un punto al final con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, funcion, indices, javascript-metodo

tengo el problema de que el valor del input , cuando inserto un punto parece que no me lo detecta en el metodo lenght (hablo a partir del for, solo despues de escribir un valor seguido del punto es que al parece ejecuta el if,no logro entender este comportamiento

```
function max6() {
var x = document.getElementById("nucleo");

if (x.value.length > x.maxLength ) {
    x.value = x.value.slice(0, x.maxLength);
}

for(a=0 ;a <= x.value.length ; a ++){
if(x.value.charAt(a)=="."){

    x.value="";
}
}
```

Este es el input

```
  <input type="number" id="nucleo" min="0" maxlength="6" oninput="max6()" name="nucleo" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Introduzca el nucleo del usuario" required>
```

Comment: Adjunta tu código html donde está el input, también el código no debe estar en imágenes, coloca el código en su respectivo formato.

Comment: Hola , muchas gracias por responder , ya adjunté los fragmentos del código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que `var x = document.getElementById("nucleo");` cuando introduces estos valores:

- **1234** => Detecta 1234 (correcto)
- **12.3** => Detecta 12.3 (correcto)
- **123.** => No detecta nada (porque no lo considera un número válido)

Entonces, no elimina el campo hasta que no se introducen los decimales que siguen el punto.

**Solución:**

Antes de realizar toda esa verificación, comprobar si `x.value` es un número con:

```
Number.isInteger(parseInt(x.value))
```

Dejo el código completo, pero no lo considero la forma más efectiva si el objetivo es no permitir decimales.

```js
function max6() {

  // Obtener input
  var x = document.getElementById("nucleo");
  
  // Comprobar si el input es un número, esto, si tiene un punto al final, directamente lo descarta
  if (!Number.isInteger(parseInt(x.value))) {
    x.value="";
    return;
  }
  
  // Acortar el número si supera el límite de dígitos
  if (x.value.length > x.maxLength ) {
      x.value = x.value.slice(0, x.maxLength);
  }

  // Si tiene decimales, reiniciar (esta parte ya sólo tiene utilidad por si hacen copy paste del número)
  for(a=0 ;a < x.value.length ; a ++){
    if(x.value.charAt(a)=="."){
        x.value="";
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!-- No se ha tocado nada -->
<input type="number" id="nucleo" oninput="max6()" min="0" maxlength="6" name="nucleo" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduzca el nucleo del usuario" required>
```

Comment: mefunciona parcialmente , funciona correctamente cuando introduzco el punto al inicio , pero no hace nada cuando lo dejo al final , y es lo que no quiero , que quede un punto al final

Comment: cual seria la forma efectiva de evitar introducir decimales ?

Comment: @harolespinosa algo mal estarías modificando, si te fijas, en el botón "Ejecutar" funciona bien. En cuanto a formas efectivas de hacerlo, con obtener el element y hacer esto es suficiente: `x.value = Math.floor(x.value);`

Comment: esta ultima respuesta es verdad que es mas efectiva , muchas gracias , problema resuelto 